# System.getProperty("gradle.user.home") returns null

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Java application that retrieves the path of **GRADLE HOME**. I created a `GRADLE_HOME` in the "Environment Variables", but `System.getProperty("gradle.user.home")` returns `null`. I also created a `GRADLE_USER_HOME` in the "Environment Variables", but `System.getProperty("gradle.user.home")` returns `null`.

Here's the image of the Environment Variables:

[image]

What's wrong? Please help me.

Comment: what do you get if you try to read System.getProperty("GRADLE_USER_HOME")?

Comment: Trt `System.getenv("GRADLE_USER_HOME")`.

Comment: Hi, it worked, but I need to get it done using System.getProperty, becuase Im using a library. I am dependent to that library.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass system property using -D command option

```
cmd>gradle -Dgradle.user.home=c:/gradle
```

You can also resolve env variable

```
cmd>gradle -Dgradle.user.home=%GRADLE_USER_HOME%
```